# BULK INSERT: FlatFile having FieldTerminator, Carriage Return and New Line characters as RowTerminator

Tags: sql-server, delimiter, bulkinsert

I am trying to import a pipe delimited flat file, but getting below errors:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

My Code:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tblImport') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb..##tblImport;

CREATE Table ##tblImport  (VoucherNumber BIGINT,Currency VARCHAR(100),VoucherAmount MONEY,  RetailAmount MONEY, VoucherDuration INT, ServiceProviderGroupID INT, BatchNumber BIGINT, SerialNumber int)

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @FilePath = 'C:\Users\Documents\Sample.txt'
    SET @SQL = 'bulk insert ##tblImport from ''C:\Users\Documents\Sample.txt''
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''|\n''
     )'

    EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##tblImport
```

If I delete the pipe at end of the row and try changing the row delimiter in the code to just '\n' I get the same error. I tried changing the type of **SERIAL NUMBER** column to **VARCHAR(MAX)** then the last column is populating all the records. Then giving space before \n again giving the above error. Can someone please help me with the code to import the data?

Comment: FIELDTERMINATOR = '' |'', ROWTERMINATOR = '' |\n''

I am getting the below error if I gave spaces before the delimiters.

**Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 8 (SerialNumber).**

Comment: FYI: the @FilePath variable is declared but not used.

Comment: Yes. I will change that. Thank you. @SQL_Underworld

Comment: What does the first row of the flat file look like? Have you looked at usage of the FIRSTROW option?

Comment: I haven't tried the FIRST ROW option. The file is not having column headers, the whole file is having the rows like this
2178058358449632|BWP|30.00|30.00|60|1|000000101205|0000000002128228|

Comment: Where is your row terminator (\n) in the example data?

Comment: Row delimiter would be '|' as well as '\n'. is it possible to have both of them? I have taken the syntax from this link. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read somewhere that in SQL Server, carriage return \r is taken by default with new line character \n (i.e., [CR][LF]). But it is not correct. My file is having Carriage Return along with New Line Character at the end of each row. So I have changed the Row Delimiter as below

```
ROWTERMINATOR = ''|\r\n''
```

It did work perfectly and my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

'|' separates the fields/columns and '|\n' separates the records/rows. That means that every record should end with '|\n' to indicate the start of the next.

Comment: Yes. But that's not happening. Something wrong with the file and I was unable find it out because when I delete the pipe delimiter at the end of each row it results nothing.

Comment: So there's something wrong with the file then, not your code?

Comment: Yes. But I need to improve my code to overcome that issue.